# How to calculate average X per Y in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a list of events, like 'pageview'. I want to calculate average pageviews per session.

My document looks like this

```
{
  sessionID: 'xxx',
  action: 'pageview'
}
```

So what I'm tried to do is to first aggregate by sessionID and then apply avg. child aggregation, but it's not what I expected.

I'm very new to ElasticSeach. What would be the logic to generate such aggregation in EC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've started correctly by aggregating on the `sessionID` field. Then you need another `filter` sub-aggregation on the `action` field to match only `pageview`actions. Your aggregation query would look like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sessions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sessionID"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "pageviews": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "action": "pageview"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is going to give you the total `doc_count` for each of your sessions and in each session bucket you'll get the total `doc_count` for `pageview` actions within that session.

The average can then easily be calculated with

```
response.aggregations.sessions.forEach(function(session) {
    var actionsInSession = session.doc_count;
    var pageviewActions = session.pageviews.doc_count;
    var avg = pageviewActions / actionsInSession;
    // do something with the average value
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you're using (or willing to use) ES 2.0, you can get ES to calculate those averages for you using [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html).

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "sessions": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "sessionID"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "total": {
               "value_count": {
                  "field": "sessionID"
               }
            },
            "pageviews": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "action": "pageview"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "cnt": {
                     "value_count": {
                        "field": "action"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "avg": {
               "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "total": "total",
                     "pageviews": "pageviews > cnt"
                  },
                  "script": "pageviews / total"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In each `sessionID` bucket, you'll get an `avg` value for the number of `pageview` action vs the number of total actions for that session.

Comment: I actually hoped to calculate averages in EC query. The idea is that this data going straight to browser and potentially there could be hundreds of thousands of sessions.